# Ivory search - Use case insensitive results

Tags: wordpress

I recently purchased a plugin called Ivory search which I would like to use on my Woo-commerce webpage. I am having issues with the plugin not being able to search in case insensitive format and with my language, Greek in general.

In the code of the plugin, I found in a file located in wp-content/plugins/add-search-to-menu-premium/admin/class-is-editor.php on line 18 the following code:

```
function is_name( $string ) {
    return preg_match( '/^[A-Za-z][-A-Za-z0-9_:.]*$/',utf8_encode($string) );
}
```

which i changed, in order to support the Greek characters.

```
function is_name( $string ) {
    return preg_match( "/^[A-Za-z0-9α-ωΑ-Ω ίϊΐόάέύϋΰήώ-]*$/", strtolower($string) );
        //return preg_match( '/^[A-Za-z][-A-Za-z0-9_:.]*$/', $string );
}
```

Some people suggested, changing the collation of the database.
http://mtdevans.com/2012/11/why-are-my-wordpress-searches-case-sensitive/ but my database is already on the proper utf8_general_ci format.

-Chancing the Database Collation
-Changing the code mentioned above, in order to support the Greek characters
-Uninstalling and re-installing the plugin mentioned
-Contacting the developers of the plugin, through their respective support page

When encountering items with lower case letters, they should be included in the search result, along with items that are lower and higher case.

Comment: I haven't had any luck so far with this.

Comment: You can contact the plugin support here https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/add-search-to-menu/